# Is information theory out of fashion?

Tags: soft-question, information-theory, research

I struggle to find research/PhD projects that use the term "information theory" in their description. I wonder why. Fields that seem to me very related, like representation learning, AI, quantitative epistemology, or some bayesian research issues, are cited without any reference to IT.

I think there is a lot still to investigate in information theory, however, it seems like few researchers are left in the field. Is that so? If it is, why?

PS: Quantum information theory probably is an exception, but outside that, it seems like nothing moves.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com may be a better home for such a question.

Comment: Maybe it's the opposite - information theory is so ubiquitous that only its various sub-disciplines get referred to these days?

Comment: The same problem occurs when you find research projects in algebraic geometry, number theory, topology, differential equations, probability and statistics, but none of them has reference to mathematics...

Comment: You made a point. If you both say so, it means that I got it completely wrong. This reassures me a lot. If some of you want to, they could make an answer of that.